# Foursquare Live Tile not updating

Tags: 8.0, live-tiles, foursquare

For some time, my Live Tile for Foursquare has not updated. I have the tile set to its smallest setting, and it shows a check-in from my wife that's a couple weeks old - and I know she and my other friends have had many check-ins since.

What could be stopping Foursquare from updating the Live Tile?

Comment: Have you been into the app recently? There are restrictions on the background processes that update live tiles that can stop if you don't use the app.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the tiles fall in a bug where they stop to update.

To fix this you need to do a process called "repin". You remove the app from start screen and after that you repin it again.

You need to check too if the background tasks are enable for this app in the settings and that you are not currently using the battery saver profile.